# What record is my Odoo widget attached to?

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo

I'm trying to wrap my head around Odoo, specifically its widgets, and it's proving to be quite frustrating because the documentation is so thin.

I'm working with a custom widget that's supposed to give a status indication on a specific record. I have to adjust the widget's view according to the state of this specific record. The widget is bound to a field on the corresponding model. Problem is: how do I know which record my widget is attached to?

*console.log(this)* is giving me the whole window.

As a shot in the dark, I added an *init*-function to my widget. With this, the code looks like:

```
odoo.define('web.web_widget_extooltip', function(require) {
    "use strict";

    var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
    var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');

    var FieldTooltip = basic_fields.FieldText.extend({
        template: 'FieldTooltip',
        widget_class: 'oe_form_field_tooltip',
        init: function (parent, name, state) {
            console.log("this is the state:", state);
            this._super(parent);
            this.name = name;
            this._initialState = state;
        },
        _renderReadonly: function () {
            var show_value = this._formatValue(this.value);
            this.$el.tooltip({'placement':'right', 'delay':0});
        },

        _renderEdit: function() {
            this.$input = this.$el.find('input');
        },
    });

    field_registry.add('extooltip', FieldTooltip);

    return FieldTooltip;
});
```

It's both a success and a complete failure: the *console.log(state)* is indeed giving me what I need, because state has a *data*-field containing the record's name, id, etc. Annoyingly, Odoo crashes immediately afterwards, saying:

```
web.assets_backend.js:1042 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined
    at Class.init (web.assets_backend.js:1042)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as init] (web.assets_common.js:3538)
    at Class.init (web.assets_backend.js:1053)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as init] (web.assets_common.js:3538)
    at Class.init (web.assets_backend.js:1054)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as init] (web.assets_common.js:3538)
    at Class.init (web.assets_backend.js:1080)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as init] (web.assets_common.js:3538)
    at Class.init (web.assets_backend.js:3304)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as init] (web.assets_common.js:3538)
```

Am I on the right track? If yes, what do I need to do to keep it from crashing? If no, what's the proper way to go about it?

Thanks!